# SELECT returns no results from psql but does from pgAdmin

Tags: command-line-interface, psql, pgadmin

I've run into an issue in which the results of a very basic query differ when comparing them between pgAdmin and psql (CLI).

In this instance the query is quite basic - **SELECT * FROM public."currentRuns"**.
I'm using the same user (postgres) in both instances.

When run in pgAdmin I'm seeing a number of results, which is expected.

When run in psql (CLI) I see no results.  I suspect there's something that I don't have configured quite right for the CLI but I'm having a hard time determining what that is.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

(forgive the links, my rep isn't high enough yet to post the actual screenshots)

[pgAdmin results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQi7x.jpg)

[psql results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiCQc.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674456/run-postgresql-queries-from-the-command-line check this question. In the answers people make some clarification between pgadmin and psql syntax.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid right about now.  All I was missing was a semi-colon at the end of my sql.

Thanks for the quick response and the clarification.  Much appreciated.