# R ODBC DBI error: database does not exist

Tags: r, postgresql, odbc

I'm working on a Mac and trying to connect to my remote Postgres database in R Studio.

#### Error

First, the error: `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: FATAL:  database "db_name" does not exist`

#### Steps taken

I first installed the necessary dependencies using homebrew:

`brew install unixodbc`

`brew install psqlodbc`

Then set up my .ini files to contain the following:

`odbcinst.ini`:

```
[PostgreSQL Driver]
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
```

`odbc.ini`:

```
[PostgreSQL]
Driver              = PostgreSQL Driver
Database            = test_db
Servername          = localhost
UserName            = postgres
Password            = password
Port                = 5432
```

In R, running the following line, to check if my driver is installed correctly, produces the expected result:

```
> odbc::odbcListDrivers()
               name attribute                       value
1 PostgreSQL Driver    Driver /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
```

I then try to connect to the database (actual names/host/pw changed), which then produces an error that the database "does not exist". All the parameters are correct, so I'm not sure what's going on. Could it be some kind of firewall/ssh protection I've set on the server side? Any help would be appreciated, I am but a humble biologist who is a bit out of my depth here.

```
> con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
+                  driver = "PostgreSQL Driver",
+                  database = "db_name",
+                  uid = "db_user",
+                  pwd = "db_pass",
+                  host = "123.456.78.910",
+                  port = 5432)
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: FATAL:  database "db_name" does not exist
```

Comment: I believe the fact that you're getting *"database does not exist"* means that you are connecting to the database and perhaps authenticating somewhat, and either the database `"db_name"` does not exist or user `"db_user"` does not have permissions to view/read/confirm its existence.

Comment: ...  that means that if you can confirm that your `host` and `port` are correct, then I suggest you check with your DBA. Have you tried to connect outside of R, perhaps with the `psql` command-line utility?

Comment: @r2evans conveniently, I am also the DBA :) yes, I connect regularly with `psql`. I'm trying to use R to automate a lot of the imports I typically do via `psql`, using the same credentials.

Comment: If it matters, I generally don't use the `/etc/odbc*` files, I use the `config` package and specify all such details directly. For that, I note that you specify different database names as `test_db` and `"db_name"`, perhaps that is the key?

Comment: A biologist and DBA? Is R running on same server as Postgres or remotely? From same machine that R is installed, please show a `psql` with that db, user, pwd, host, port that runs a [simple query call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674456/run-postgresql-queries-from-the-command-line) at command line.

Comment: @Parfait Postgres server is remote. I have no issues using `psql`. I'm trying to build a simple R Shiny app to import & explore data. Trying to teach others in the lab how to use command line hasn't been fruitful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much later answer to my own question: after shelving this project for a few months, I came back to it and tried a different driver approach using the `RPostgres` package. Specifically, rather than messing around with the `odbc` driver and .ini file, I instead tried `RPostgres::Postgres()`.

```
drv <- RPostgres::Postgres()
db <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = drv, 
               user = "user",
               password = "pwd",
               dbname = "dbname",
               host = "123.456.78.910")
DBI::dbGetQuery(db, "select * from my_table")
```

Answer (score 1):

First it seems your pg database is local on your mac (localhost, same for me), you don't have then to specify your IP in R.

What happen if you type this? Because your DSN for db_test / db_name is [PostgreSQL] in reality (.odbc.ini).

```r
library(DBI)
con_odbc_to_db_name <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "PostgreSQL")
```

or if it doesn't work maybe test the same with "db_name", "db_test" / "test_db". But I think your problem is just that "PostgreSQL" name in odbc.ini.

For a more complete answer on this, and to do sort of a memo pad.

### PostgreSQL odbc and DSN definitions on a Mac.

For odbc, there are two files:

- odbcinst.ini in /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini to specify driver name (you choose)
- .odbc.ini in your $HOME (~), to be created first time to specify data source names (odbc DSN)

#### nano /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini

You have to correctly indicate the driver name ODBC somewhere (and use it after in .odbc.ini).

For a complete overview of this setup on a Mac, there is a very good blog post on these odbc/obdcinst, see [here](https://www.boriel.com/postgresql-odbc-connection-from-mac-os-x.html).

You will see that you have coherent [Driver] between odbcinst.ini file and the driver that is specified in .odbc.ini `Driver = ...` for your DSN

```
# nano  /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
[PostgreSQL Unicode]
Description     = PostgreSQL ODBC driver (Unicode version)
Driver          = psqlodbcw.so
Debug           = 0
CommLog         = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

Capture:
[image: [https://www.boriel.com/postgresql-odbc-connection-from-mac-os-x.html](Boirel blog post)]

#### nano ~/.odbc.ini

With DBI/odbc packages you can pass connections parameters inside .odbc.ini for each database, for instance:

*Note that you have to put your db name inside `[...]` (ODBC Data Source Name) at the beginning of each definition.*

```
# .odbc.ini contains:
[db_name]
Driver      = PostgreSQL Unicode
ServerName  = localhost
Port        = 5432
Database    = db_name
Username    = usr
Password    = pwd
Protocol    = 13.0.3
Debug       = 1

[db_test]
Driver      = PostgreSQL Unicode
ServerName  = localhost
Port        = 5432
Database    = db_test
Username    = usr
Password    = pwd
Protocol    = 13.0.3
Debug       = 1
```

### test connection in RStudio

Your database then will appear in Rstudio Connections Pane like this, for me my database is "pmsi" here instead of "db_name".

[image: connection pane]

After that, to connect in R, it's easier: you just have to click on your db_name row in this window, or more precisely, type this:

```r
library(DBI)
con_odbc_to_db_name <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "db_name")
```

#### And about RPostgres package

However I've found personally that writing big tables (many row, many cols) in pg with `odbc`/`DBI` dbWriteTable is a bit slow. For this I use `RPostgres` package which uses `\COPY` to "bulk" insert raw datas:

```r
con_to_db_name <- RPostgres::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), "db_name")
# change default schema after that if neeeded
DBI::dbSendQuery(cidd2, "SET search_path = db_preferred_schema, public;")
```

And then use the good `dbWriteTable` from `RPosgres`:

```r
RPostgres::dbWriteTable(con_to_db_name,  "db_table_a", table_a, append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this thorough answer. No - it's not `localhost`, it's a remote DigitalOcean server. I'd like to avoid putting credentials in the .ini files as I'm developing a Shiny application that other users might use. As for `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "PostgreSQL")` - result: `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: then it seems to work, it seems you have to set correct user to connect to your database or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist